# Boxplots of numeric variable grouped by logical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have a dataset with one numeric variable (PTV), and two categorical variables (habit and ffg) which are listed as logical for each category within those two. So I have a series of columns named HABIT_BU, FFG_SH, FFG_SC. How would I create box plots where each box is the PTV of observations that are TRUE for each category. And how would I format it so that the end result looks something like this plot?[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You are much more likely to receive a useful answer if you provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's asumme you have the following dataset:

```r
PTV = rnorm(100)
HABIT_BU = c(rep(TRUE,50),rep(FALSE,50))
FFG_SH =  c(rep(TRUE,50),rep(FALSE,50))
FFG_SC =  c(rep(TRUE,50),rep(FALSE,50))

df <- data.frame(PTV, HABIT_BU, FFG_SH, FFG_SC)
```

And so the dummy dataset looks like:

```r
> head(df)
          PTV HABIT_BU FFG_SH FFG_SC
1 -0.14361156     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
2 -1.36115367     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
3  0.68461065     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
4 -0.40292344     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
5 -0.01070836     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
6  0.44495130     TRUE   TRUE   TRUE

> str(df)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ PTV     : num  -0.1436 -1.3612 0.6846 -0.4029 -0.0107 ...
 $ HABIT_BU: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ FFG_SH  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ FFG_SC  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

Does it correspond to your actual dataset ? (If not, please provide a reproducible dataset)

Now, we can reshape your data using `tidyr`

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-PTV, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values")

# A tibble: 300 x 3
      PTV Variable Values
    <dbl> <chr>    <lgl> 
 1 -0.144 HABIT_BU TRUE  
 2 -0.144 FFG_SH   TRUE  
 3 -0.144 FFG_SC   TRUE  
 4 -1.36  HABIT_BU TRUE  
 5 -1.36  FFG_SH   TRUE  
 6 -1.36  FFG_SC   TRUE  
 7  0.685 HABIT_BU TRUE  
 8  0.685 FFG_SH   TRUE  
 9  0.685 FFG_SC   TRUE  
10 -0.403 HABIT_BU TRUE  
# … with 290 more rows
```

And we can plot it using `ggplot`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-PTV, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x = Values, y = PTV, fill = Values))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(.~Variable)
```

To get this boxplot:
[image]

If you want to plot only values that are TRUE for each category, you can use the function `filter` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-PTV, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") %>% filter(., Values == TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x = Values, y = PTV, fill = Values))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(.~Variable)
```

And you get:
[image]

Or as all your category contains only a single value, you can plot them like this:

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(.,-PTV, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") %>% filter(., Values == TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x = Variable, y = PTV, fill = Variable))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

If not, please consider to provide a reproducible example of your dataset (see here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome !